# Can I use a string as an end of line delimiter when importing a .csv to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, csv

Very basic question but I'm struggling with it. When importing a `.csv` file to MySQL, is it possible to use any character or string as an end of line delimiter?

If so is it possible from the admin window 'Import'? Or must I do so in an SQL query (doesnt seem logical).

So far, I have had issues using everything besides \n and auto in the PHP my admin window. I tried the `€` sign and also `///`. Didn't work and got errors relating to an incorrect end of line  delimiter.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using SQL [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) `.. LINES TERMINATED BY 'string'`

Comment: Thank you. My only problem with this is that this requires me to open an SQL statement separately instead of having the nice "Import" tab which allows me to upload my CSV file from thte desktop . When using SQL command im forced to specify a filepath on my server it says my @localhost user's passowrd in not accepted. In the import tap I thought i could just put € after 'Lines terminated with:' in the tab but no luck.

Comment: "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" will allow from the local machine, if the connection was started with the loaddata local option.